# If range of the activation function is smaller than that of data, the last layer of the decoder should be kept linear. Why?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, recommender-system

[Training Deep AutoEncoders for Collaborative Filtering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.01715) paper tells that

> "**If range of the activation function is smaller than that of data,
> the last layer of the decoder should be kept linear.**"

Can someone explain and elaborate this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last layer of autoencoders, you'll be regressing your input back. So, if the input data has a larger range than that of activation function, last layer's activation is dropped so that the neuron outputs have actually the ability to regress the output range. You could've sometimes convert your input to the output range of the activation function, but typically the former method is preferred. This is even crucial when the data range is unbounded.

Comment: If I convert my input to the output range of the activation function, will I miss out on something else? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You can do that if input range is bounded, e.g. converting 0-255 pixel values to 0-1 and using sigmoid activation. But, also, zero mean inputs are typically better for neural nets, which is why standardised inputs are fed to them. It helps the gradient descent.